# MongoDB: aggregate lookup in deeply nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections:

Audios

```
[
       {
        "_id": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "audioURL": "https://boyd.org",
        "state": "draft",
       }
       {
        "_id": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
        "name": "navigate",
        "audioURL": "http://mariane.org",
        "state": "draft",
       },
       {
        "_id": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
        "audioURL": "https://storage/test123mp31599820832928.mp3",
        "state": "draft",
       }
]
```

Lessons:

```
 "lessons": [
  {
   "_id": "5f770e275cef7a611f3cf931",
   "minigameDescriptions": [
    {
     "assessmentSections": [
      {
       "mark": "step_1",
       "start": 1,
       "end": 2,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7"
       }
      },
      {
       "mark": "step_2",
       "start": 3,
       "end": 6,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3"
       }
      },
      {
       "mark": "step_3",
       "start": 7,
       "end": 10,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504"
       }
      }
     ],
     "drumStyleName": "DrumStyleHalftimeShuffle",
     "onboarding": false,
     "showHints": false,
     "minigameType": "StrummingTrainer",
    }
   ],
   "_updated_at": "2020-10-02T12:00:23.848Z",
  }
 ]
}
```

Now I have to aggregate that because in every `mingameDescriptions.assessmentSections` there is property `stepAudio` that has `previewTrackAudioId` and `backingTrackAudioId`. These references to collection "audios" and I need to join them there as objects (audio primary key is `_id`). I've tried following pipeline (right now I only try to lookup for `previewTrackAudio` ):

```
{
        $unwind: {
          path: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "audios",
          let: {
            audioId: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.stepAudio.previewTrackAudioId"
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $eq: ["$_id", "$$audioId"]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.stepAudio.previewTrackAudio"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          path: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.stepAudio.previewTrackAudio"
        }
      }
```

And it "kinda" works, I get following result:

```
{
 "lessons": [
  {
   "_id": "5f770e275cef7a611f3cf931",
   "minigameDescriptions": [
    {
     "assessmentSections": {
      "mark": "step_2",
      "start": 3,
      "end": 6,
      "stepAudio": {
       "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
       "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
       "previewTrackAudio": {
        "_id": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
        "name": "navigate",
        "audioURL": "http://mariane.org",
        "state": "draft",
       }
      }
     },
     "drumStyleName": "DrumStyleHalftimeShuffle",
     "onboarding": false,
     "showHints": false,
     "minigameType": "StrummingTrainer",
    },
    {
     "assessmentSections": {
      "mark": "step_3",
      "start": 7,
      "end": 10,
      "stepAudio": {
       "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
       "previewTrackAudioId": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
       "previewTrackAudio": {
        "_id": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
        "audioURL": "https://storage/test123mp31599820832928.mp3",
        "state": "draft",
       }
      }
     },
     "drumStyleName": "DrumStyleHalftimeShuffle",
     "onboarding": false,
     "showHints": false,
     "minigameType": "StrummingTrainer",
    },
    {
     "assessmentSections": {
      "mark": "step_1",
      "start": 1,
      "end": 2,
      "stepAudio": {
       "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
       "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
       "previewTrackAudio": {
        "_id": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "audioURL": "https://boyd.org",
        "state": "draft",
       }
      }
     },
     "drumStyleName": "DrumStyleHalftimeShuffle",
     "onboarding": false,
     "showHints": false,
     "minigameType": "StrummingTrainer",
    }
   ],
   "_updated_at": "2020-10-02T12:00:23.848Z",
  }
 ]
}
```

But now instead of having an array with 3 `mingameDescriptions.assessmentSections` I have an array with three objects that have `assesmentSections` along with duplicate properties from `minigameDescriptions` which is wrong :/. How can I fix this?

What I would like to get is:

```
 "lessons": [
  {
   "_id": "5f770e275cef7a611f3cf931",
   "minigameDescriptions": [
    {
     "assessmentSections": [
      {
       "mark": "step_1",
       "start": 1,
       "end": 2,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "previewTrackAudio": {
         "_id": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
         "audioURL": "https://boyd.org",
         "state": "draft",
        }
       }
      },
      {
       "mark": "step_2",
       "start": 3,
       "end": 6,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f6b1e1c6297f34bc6f1fee3",
        "previewTrackAudio": {
          "_id": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
          "audioURL": "https://storage/test123mp31599820832928.mp3",
          "state": "draft",
         }
       }
      },
      {
       "mark": "step_3",
       "start": 7,
       "end": 10,
       "stepAudio": {
        "backingTrackAudioId": "5f6b1a2e69eef14818ca03a7",
        "previewTrackAudioId": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
        "previewTrackAudio": {
         "_id": "5f5b5423ba39f738d593b504",
         "audioURL": "https://storage/test123mp31599820832928.mp3",
         "state": "draft",
        }
       }
      }
     ],
     "drumStyleName": "DrumStyleHalftimeShuffle",
     "onboarding": false,
     "showHints": false,
     "minigameType": "StrummingTrainer",
    }
   ],
   "_updated_at": "2020-10-02T12:00:23.848Z",
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You need to post both collections. And don't post unnecessary fields which make uncomfortable to others while looking into it

Comment: Right, I've posted both collections and removed the unnecessary fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried was correct.

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$minigameDescriptions"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Audios",
      let: {
        audioId: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.stepAudio.previewTrackAudioId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$audioId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.stepAudio.previewTrackAudio"
    }
  },
      {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        /**   assId: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections.mark"*/
        
      },
      assessmentSections: {
        $addToSet: "$minigameDescriptions.assessmentSections"
      },
      drumStyleName: {
        $first: "$minigameDescriptions.drumStyleName"
      },
      minigameType: {
        $first: "$minigameDescriptions.minigameType"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      minigameDescriptions: {
        $addToSet: {
          assessmentSections: "$assessmentSections",
          drumStyleName: "$drumStyleName",
          minigameType: "$minigameType"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pMkGQ9R7QMh)**

Note: Here we have done two unwinds, so better to perform to group operation. Carefule, I have commented `assessmentId` in first group which is not present in your document. But better if have anything to identify each element in `assessmentSections` which helps not to be complicated

Comment: It's almost what I need, thanks! I have edited the post to add what response I need, since in your solution I only get the `assessmentSections`, and the remaining properties from `minigameDescriptions` are missing. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I've updated my answer I've done for few fields, you can follow same way

Comment: Does that help you?

Comment: I will check that later and let you know!